# Django print loop index inside List

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I am trying to print the list of values from a list. This code works:

```
 <td id="b0">{{data.0.B}}</td>
 <td id="b1">{{data.1.B}}</td>
 <td id="b2">{{data.2.B}}</td>
 <td id="b3">{{data.3.B}}</td>
```

I am trying to put this in a loop like so:

```
 {% for i in data%}
    <td id ='b{{forloop.counter0}}'>
        Data is{{  data.forloop.counter0.B }}
    </td>
 {% endfor %}
```

This prints the td id as b0, b1 etc correctly. However it is unable to replace the forloop.counter0 inside data.forloop.counter0.B and is not printing it as data.0.B, data.1.B etc.

How do I change the code so that data.forloop.counter0.B is printed in the loop as data.0.B, data.1.B etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
{% for i in data%}
    <td id ='b{{forloop.counter0}}'>
        Data is{{  i.B }}
    </td>
 {% endfor %}
```